# CORS + WCF (SOAP)

Tags: wcf, soap, cors

I have a problem with the integration of CORS and WCF (SOAP, not REST).
When I do a request from js, an exception is "The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty" in the WCF Trace log (logically, in connection with the OPTION CORS request)

Body:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/">
    <s:Header>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"></GetInfo>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

JS request:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:8081/service_deploy/service1.svc/serviceSoap",    
   headers: { "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/IService/GetInfo" },
   data: body,      
   contentType: "text/xml",   
   timeout: 10000
});
```

CORS request:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8081/service_deploy/service1.svc/serviceSoap
HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:49209
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,soapaction
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Exception:

```
Type: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Mes: There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. See inner exception for more details.
  Inner type: System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
  Inner mes: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

How can I integrate CORS and WCF SOAP or handle this low-level WCF exception?

Comment: Can you show an example of your js request?

Comment: Hmm, really interesting question, really stretches WCF extensibility to the limit :) I think this can be done e.g. with a custom channel, or even a custom encoder, but don't remember all that well how the WCF message processing pipeline works anymore - it would help if you posted the actual type of the exception and all inner exception info - this would help me find the exact place where empty messages are detected.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I posted some additional information about the request and exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need a filter in your servlet container which handles the OPTIONS requests and answers with the appropriate headers set.

Your `web.xml` file could look like this

```
[...]
<filter>
   <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>my.namespace.CORSFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CORSFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
[...]
```

And this is an example of a CORS filter

```
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
  // For security reasons set this regex to an appropriate value
  // example: ".*example\\.com"
  private static final String ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP = ".*";

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
      ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
    if (origin != null && origin.matches(ALLOWED_DOMAINS_REGEXP)) {
      resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
      if ("options".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
        resp.setHeader("Allow", "GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS");
        if (origin != null) {
          String headers = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
          String method = req.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
          resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", method);
          resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
          resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        }
        resp.getWriter().flush();
        return;
      }
    }

    // Fix the ios6 issue: caching post requests
    if ("post".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
      resp.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }

    if (filterChain != null) {
      filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
  }

  @Override public void destroy() {}
  @Override public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If used Java technology, I would use the same approach. However, the technology was used is Microsoft WCF. WCF has a similar approach (Behavior) but an exception is raised before.